# Variable Grid Maker

Tags: file, batch-file

I have been working on a batch file that creates a grid of variables like this:

```
%G1%%G2%%G3%%G4%%G5% 
%G6%%G7%%G8%%G9%%G10% 
%G11%%G12%%G13%%G14%%G15%
```

but when I try running my batch file it just writes this:

```
%G1%%G2%%G3%%G4%%G5%
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
Echo is off.
```

I have added the code here please could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
@echo off
title GirdMaker
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set lineid=0
set COLS=0
set LINES=0
set /p LINES=Enter number of lines:
set /p COLS=Enter the number of colums:
cls
set START=1
set linecount=0
:A
set LINE=
for /l %%I in (%START%,1,%COLS%) do (
set LINE=!LINE!%%G%%I%%
)
set /a linecount=%linecount%+1
echo %LINE% 
set /a lineid=%lineid%+%COLS%+1
set START=%lineid%

if %LINES% EQU %linecount% (
pause >nul
exit
) 
goto :A
```

Comment: I can't see where do you create the variables `G1`, `G2`, ... nor where do you try to access them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze this part:

```
:A
set LINE=
for /l %%I in (%START%,1,%COLS%) do (
set LINE=!LINE!%%G%%I%%
)
```

First loop iteration create this: `set LINE=%G1%` right? Second loop iteration: `set LINE=%G1%%G2%` and so on until `set LINE=%G1%%G2%%G3%%G4%%G5%`, right?

Now, this line:

```
echo %LINE%
```

Is first expanded this way:

```
echo %G1%%G2%%G3%%G4%%G5%
```

and *NOT* expanded again, because % expansion is just done once from left to right. The result is:

```
%G1%%G2%%G3%%G4%%G5%
```

Excuse me, but you did NOT tell us what you expect to get from your program, but if you expect to show the values of variables G1 to G5, then you must *restart* the % expansion this way:

```
call echo %LINE%
```

About your other lines, you must carefully check the limits; it is obvious that LINE variable is empty in those cases.

**EDIT**: Perhaps is this what you want?

```
set /p LINES=Enter number of lines: 
set /p COLS=Enter the number of colums: 
set index=0
for /L %%I in (1,1,%LINES%) do (
   set LINE=
   for /L %%J in (1,1,%COLS%) do (
      set /A index+=1
      set LINE=!LINE!%%G!index!%%
   )
   call echo !LINE!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adjusting your end position in the for loop, so the contents are never running after the first line (`START` is already greater than `COLS`), consequently `LINE` is left empty and your call to `echo` is empty.

You need to change this:

```
for /l %%I in (%START%,1,%COLS%) do (
```

Which is trying to loop from (1-5, 6-5, 11-5).
To something like this:

```
set /a ENDCOL = %START% + %COLS% - 1
for /l %%I in (%START%,1,%ENDCOL%) do (
```

That way, it will loop from 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 etc...

Comment: `%COLS%` is user specified though, how is it greater than `%START%` if we don't actually know what it is?

Comment: @BaliC: COLS isn't > START, START is > COLS, because after the first line loop, the script does `set /a lineid=%lineid%+%COLS%+1`, which sets the value of START to > COLS when it starts doing the columns on the second / third etc rows. On the first row, START was equal to 1, so the for loop was executing.